# Ui-sref routing parameters not passed

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Here's my state definition:

```
    .state('root.countryreport', {
        url: '/report/:country',
        params: {
            data: null
        },
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/country_dashboard.html',
                controller: 'countryReportController'
            }
        }
    })
```

And here's my a href:

```
<a ui-sref="root.countryreport({data: {id: item.id}, country: lowercase(item.title)})">
    {{ item.title }}
</a>
```

The data parameter is passed as null no matter what I do.
What am I doing wrong? The country parameter is passed as expected.

I am using angular-ui-router: 0.2.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you defaulted its value to `null`, so in current case even if you pass value to `data` it will always set to `null`

You need to make default value as `null` when nothing has passed to it by having `{value: 'defaultvalue'}` expression.

**Code**

```
params: {
    data: {
       value: null
    }
},
```

Comment: Tried that, now the value is being passed as null.

Comment: Funny thing is I'm using the same thing in another project, but I'm calling a function that does: $state.go(route, params); - it works like a charm there. Just this ui-sref isn't

Comment: I think above should work..could you try to do cache clear of browser and check..

Comment: Even my original code is working.. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I thimk for newer version of ui-router your approch would not work.. Which version of ui-router you are using?